# python function for filling missing values through some classifier like algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I would like to input missing data with python in an "intelligent" way.

I have come to scikit-learn and pandas imputation through "mean" and "median", but I want imputation through machine learning, statistical algorithms, classifiers..., in order to have unique values based on the values of all the data. Basically like a classifier learning algorithm predicting the missing value (located in any part of my dataset).

Is there anything like this?

Comment: In scikit-learn soon: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the fancyimpute library, though it doesn't play well with scikit-learn for now, as far as I know.
We're planning to have better imputations models in scikit-learn, soon, in particular IterativeImputer seems to be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11977

Comment: Really interesting, this is what I was lookin for. I tried similar things in R with Amelia package I think. At least there is some way to fill the missing data looking at other fields/columns of the matrix/dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is called interpolation. There are different techniques for doing this.

If you are using pandas DataFrame for reading/handling the data try:

```
pandas.DataFrame.interpolate
```

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but with this method it uses all other fields to fill the missing value? For example if I have a dataframe with a, b, c fields and only a missing value in row=2 column=b it takes in consideration the values of row=2 columns=a,c ?
Nevertheless its very interesting, I used it a couple of times with a basic lineal method.